# Best Windows Start Position for Forms to make them open on same display starting form is on?

Tags: winforms

My Windows Forms application has a lot of forms, and they are opened and closed a lot. I need the forms to always open on the same display that my starting form is currently sitting on (the form that is specified in Application.Run()).
That is how my application always behaved, but since migrating from VS19 to VS22, I have been unable to get the same behavior again. What StartPosition should I be using, or any other settings to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! This makes the form you are currently opening, open on the same display that your initial startup form is currently on, and centers it to that form. Essentially it is manually creating the CenterParent StartPosition without dealing with Parents/Children.

Here is my code for opening my MainMenu Form:

```
            form = new MainMenu();
            form.Location = Program.getStartFormPoint(form.Width, form.Height);
            form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            form.Show();
```

The two middle lines are what I added for this solution. Below will be the getStartFormPoint function that in this example I placed in my Program.cs. LoginScreen/loginForm is my initial startup form in this Application. The same form that is used in Application.Run under Main().

```
public static Point getStartFormPoint(int width, int height)
{
    var loginForm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<LoginScreen>().FirstOrDefault();
    Point thePoint = new Point((loginForm.Location.X + loginForm.Width / 2) - (width / 2), (loginForm.Location.Y + loginForm.Height / 2) - (height / 2));
    return (thePoint);
}
```